# Where is a postgresql 9.1 database stored in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: database, postgresql

I installed and created a Postgresql database on ubuntu. I then created the database using the following command:

```
sudo su postgres createdb mydatabase
```

However, I can't figure out where the database was initialized. I would like to be able to edit the `hba.conf` file and `postgresl.conf` files.

When I view the database using pgadmin I see the following information:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Any thoughts on how I can find the database cluster location?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `postgres.conf` file is located here: `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgres.conf`. In `postgres.conf` can see a line stating `data_directory=<path>`

This is the directory where your database files are stored

Alternatively when you are connected to database use

```
SHOW data_directory
```

or

```
pg_lsclusters
```

to show the directory where your data is stored.

Hope this helps

Comment: For me, it was not `postgres.conf` but `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Thanks,I was able to find this line following your answer, but unfortunately, we cannot cd into this directory:`/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`, I guess it's by design for safety and integrity of the data?

Answer (score 6):

```
ps auxw|grep postgres|grep -- -D
```

returns:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main 
-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

on Ubuntu 14.04.  That command will work on other variants like Fedora